# LaTeX template from university doesn't work with sectsty

Tags: koma-script, templates, sectsty

I got a `LaTeX` template from my university to work with and tried changing some chapter font size and number because of them getting really huge (3 line wraps for one heading).

I found the `sectsty` and `titlesec` packages, however when I try to apply any ne of them, I don't see any changes happening. I assume that some of the predefined packages are colliding with the changes of `sectsty/titlesec`, but I don't know which ones.

Here is the template (and some commented out `sectsty` code)

```
% EES Latex-Vorlage Februar 2022

\documentclass[
12pt,                                                   
% Schriftgröße
a4paper,                                                    
% Layout für DINA4
german,                                                     
% deutsche Sprache, global
twoside,                                                    
% Layout für beidseitigen Druck
headinclude,                                            
% Kopfzeile wird Seiten-Layouts mit berücksichtigt
headsepline,                                            
% horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel
plainheadsepline,                                       
% horizontale Linie unter Kolumnentitel auch bei Chapter
BCOR=20mm,                                              
% Korrektur für die Bindung
DIV=18,                                             
% DIV-Wert für die Erstellung des Satzspiegels, siehe scrguide
parskip=half,                                           
% Absatzabstand statt Absatzeinzug
openany,                                                    
% Kapitel künnen auf geraden und ungeraden Seiten beginnen
bibliography=totoc,version=first,                       
% Literaturverz. wird ins Inhaltsverzeichnis eingetragen
numbers=noenddot,                                   
% Kapitelnummern immer ohne Punkt
captions=tableheading,version=first,                    
% korrekte Abstände bei Tabellenüberschriften
fleqn,                                                  
% fleqn: Glgen links (statt mittig)
listof=totoc,version=first,                             
% Abbildungs- und Tabellenverzeichnis ins Inhaltsverzeichnis
cleardoublepage=empty,                          
% Kopfzeile bei leeren Seiten entfernen
footheight =22pt,
]{scrbook}


%--------------- Packages ----------------
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                         
% Neue deutsche Trennmuster
\usepackage[format=hang,                            
% Captions ausrichten
justification=raggedright,
singlelinecheck=off,
labelfont=bf,
font=small,
skip=4pt
]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                
% T1-Schriften
\usepackage{lmodern}                                
% moderne Schriften                                             
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}                    
% AMS-Mathematik, centertags zentriert Nummer bei split
\usepackage{tabularx}                               
% erweiterte Tabellen
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       
% zum Einbinden von Grafiken
\usepackage{setspace}                                       
% Zeilenabstand einstellbar
\usepackage{hyperref}       
% Die Links im PDF werden nur noch dünn und rot unterstrichen, nicht mehr fett umrahmt. 
\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 0}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}                               
% Kopf- und Fußzeilen-Layout 
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}  

% benutzerdefinierte Textpositionierung
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\chapterfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}

%--------------- Sonstiges ----------------
\pagestyle{scrheadings}                                 
% Kopf- und Fußzeile...
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}          
% Kolumnentitel serifenlos
\renewcommand{\pnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}          
% Seitennummern serifenlos
\ihead[]{\headmark}                                             
% Kopfzeile innen
\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}                                
% Kopfzeile außen
\ifoot[]{}                                              
% Fußzeile innen
\ofoot[]{}                                                  
% Fußzeile außen    
\setlength{\headheight}{1.5\baselineskip}
\onehalfspacing                                         
% 1,5 Zeilenabstand
%\typearea[current]{current}                                    
% Neuberechnung des Satzspiegels mit alten Werten nach Änderung von Zeilenabstand,etc
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Literatur und Quellen}          
% Literaturverzeichnisbezeichnung
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}                        
% Abbildungsbezeichnung
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}   
% Abbildungsverzeichnisbezeichnung
\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\small}                     
% Bildunterschriften klein kursiv
\graphicspath{{figs/}{bilder/}}                             
% Bildverzeichnis

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=0pt]{chapter}       
%kein Abstand zum oberen Seitenrand bei neuen Kapiteln


\makeindex

%Bestimmt Ebene Unterüberschriften Gliederung
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%Bestimmt Ebene Unterüberschriften toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}


%----------------------- Beginn des Dokuments -----------------------
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}                                   
% Römische Seitennummerierung

\include{inhalt/deckblatt}                              
% Deckblatt
\include{inhalt/erklaerung}                             
% Erklärung der Eigenarbeit
\include{inhalt/aufgabe}                                    
% Aufgabenstellung (optional)
\include{inhalt/vorwort}                                    
% Vorwort (optional)
\cleardoublepage
\begin{spacing}{1.05}                                   
% evtl. kleinerer Zeilenabstand im IV, AV, TV
\pdfbookmark[1]{Inhaltsverzeichnis}{toc}                    
% Inhaltsverzeichnis bei den Lesezeichen rein
\tableofcontents                                            
% Inhaltsverzeichnis erzeugen
\end{spacing}

\include{inhalt/abstract}                                   
% Abstract

\mainmatter                                             
% Hauptteil beginnt
\include{inhalt/1einleitung}                                    
% Einleitung (Bezeichnung passend zur Arbeit!)
\include{inhalt/2grundlagenundtheoretischerhintergrund}
\include{inhalt/3analytischeberechnung} 
\include{inhalt/4numerischeberechnung1}
\include{inhalt/5numerischeberechnung2}
\include{inhalt/6diskussionderergebnissezurrealisierungeinerfgasfreien550kvdcgis}
%\include{inhalt/hauptteil}                                 
% Hauptteil (Bezeichnung passend zur Arbeit!)
\include{inhalt/7fazitundausblick}                          

\appendix                                               
% Anhang
%\include{inhalt/anhang}                                    
% Anhangsinhalt
\include{inhalt/symbole}                                    
% Symbol- und Abkürzungsverzeichnis

\begin{spacing}{1.5}                                        
% evtl. kleinerer Zeilenabstand im LV
%\nocite{*}                                                 
% alle Literaturquellen einbinden, sonst werden nur die zitierten
% Quellen im Literaturverzeichnis angezeigt.
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}                                    
% Darstellung numerisch nach Vorkommen im Text
\bibliography{Quellen_Kapitel1.1}
\listoffigures                                              
% Abbildungsverzeichnis
\listoftables                                               
% Tabellenverzeichnis
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
%------------------------- Ende des Dokuments -----------------------
```

Comment: Use `\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\sffamily}` instead of `sectsty`.

Comment: You could also consider making your chapter titles shorter, for example instead of "Diskussion der Ergebnisse zur Realisierung einer fgasfreien 550kvdcgis" you could call it "Diskussion" or "Realisierung" or "Fgasfreien 550kvdcgis" or something. Short titles help the reader get a quick overview and makes navigation of the document easier.

Comment: If you use your official university template is not recommend to change defined style. Better is to consider @Marijn comment.